# How to sort an array in Javascript like C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort an array in JavaScript as asc. After I used sort method, the result is like below.

`[ '123, '12', '1A1', '1A', '1a', 'A1', 'A2', 'AB', 'A', 'Ab', 'a1', 'a2', 'aB', 'ab' ]`

When I'm using sort `Array.Sort()` by C#, the result is like below.

`{ "12", "123", "1a", "1A", "1A1", "A", "a1", "A1", "a2", "A2", "ab", "aB", "Ab", "AB" }`

Actually the C# sort way is what I want, so how to implement it in JavaScript? Has anyone completed this task before? A comparator function is really appreciate.

Comment: why this is down vote and the answers are up votes. Don't get it, write a new function is not the answer of the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The order he specifies is actually what C# Array.Sort gives.

Comment: Have you notice that A is a single character? I guess so C# has special operation inside the sort method for it. Suppose C# sort is an expected result, now I want to use JavaScript to match it.

Comment: Here's the ideone.com for it... http://ideone.com/ZLKC8M It looks as though C# is ordering the string multiple times, going through the characters one by one, e.g. OrderBy([0]).ThenBy([1]).ThenBy([2]) and so on

Comment: @PaulZahra: *"The order he specifies is actually what C# Array.Sort gives"* Yeah, I just worked that through using csharppad. Very surprising!

Comment: @Damon Array.Sort() states... This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved

Comment: @PaulZahra: Yeah, but I checked, these results are stable. (I was kind of hoping they weren't...) http://csharppad.com/gist/6ca6dde9cff28207f702 At least in whatever locale CSharpPad uses...

Comment: @Damon see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331850/array-sort-in-with-nontrivial-comparison-function

Comment: @Damon I removed my question about writing own JavaScript function based on decompiled C# code. C# uses InternalCompareString Windows API function and there are too lot of conditions... It will be easier to write your own C# delegate function for sorting rather than investigate implementation of InternalCompareString Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.sort` uses string comparison by default. It seems you want to compare case insensitive - you could pass in a comparator function that uses `toLowerCase` (but beware of the difference with `.toLocaleLowerCase`!):

```
a.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase(); b = b.toLowerCase();
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
});
```